# jquery hide div when click search button and display result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

newbie here, having problem with my jquery right now. When I clicked search the result is posted on the right div, only problem is the div1 is not being able to hide. Help please.

Here is the composition of my code so far. Just really getting messed up with the hide function of the div id=tab1

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/sample.js"></script>
<script src="./js/quicksearch.js"></script>
<script src="./js/lytebox.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/sample.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/table_blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/lytebox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script>

$(function () {

    var $dtps = $("#datepicker, #datepicker2"); //use a class selector to simplify this

    $dtps.hide().datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
    });
    $("#category").on('change', function () {
        $dtps.toggle(this.value == 'ORIGINAL_DEADLINE')
    });
    //should be outside of the change event hanlder
    $("#cmdsearch").click(function () {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $("#tab1").hide();
        $("#tab_result").show();
    });
});
</script>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Overdue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Next 60 days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Others</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">No Deadline</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Finished Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="./reg.php">Register User</a></li>
        <li><a href="./report.php">Generate Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="./manage_users.php">Manage Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form method="post" action="beta_table.php">
        Category<select name="category" id="category">
        <option value='APP_NUMBER' >APP_NUMBER</option>
        <option value='SPOC_ASSIGNED' >SPOC_ASSIGNED</option>
        <option value='BORROWER_NAME' >BORROWER_NAME</option>
        <option value='DEFERRED_TYPE' >DEFERRED_TYPE</option>
        <option value='ORIGINAL_DEADLINE' >ORIGINAL_DEADLINE</option>
        </select>
        Search Text<input type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Type to Search" />
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1" placeholder="Input Start Date"/> 
        <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2" placeholder="Input End Date"/>  
        <input type="submit" id="cmdsearch" name="cmdsearch" value="Search" />
    </form>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active" >
          <?php
        //conection: 
    include "conn.php";
     //consultation: 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM export_workflow.COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),ORIGINAL_DEADLINE)>1 and SUBMITTED_PENDING='PENDING'"; 
     //execute the query. 
     if($result = $link->query($query)){
           echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".
                 "</tr>";

          }
          $result->close();
          echo "</table>\r\n";
        } else {
          printf("<p>Error: %s</p>\r\n", $mysqli->error);
        }
        ?>    
        </div>

        <div id="tab_result">
            <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['cmdsearch'])){
        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $text=$_POST['txtsearch'];
        $date1=$_POST['date1'];
        $date2=$_POST['date2'];



//connect to db

     $link = mysqli_connect("10.20.8.70","stcutie","qwerty123","export_workflow") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
     if($link->connect_error){
          printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
          exit();
     }

    if($category==='ORIGINAL_DEADLINE'){
         $sql="SELECT * FROM COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where ($category BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')";

    }else{
            $sql="SELECT * FROM COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT where $category LIKE '%$text%'";

    }

    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);

            }

        $result = $link->query($sql);
         echo "<table class='data' id='table_example'>".
                "<thead>".
                "<tr>".
                "<td>App Number</td>".
                "<td>Spoc Assigned</td>".
                "<td>Borrower Name</td>".
                "<td>App Finish Date</td>".
                "<td>Developer & Project</td>".
                "<td>Collateral Address Details</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Document</td>".
                "<td>Deferred Type</td>".
                "<td>Original Deadline</td>".
                "<td>Date Completed</td>".
                "<td>SPOC Remarks</td>".
                "<td>File Location</td>".
                "<td>JUW MA Remarks</td>".
                "<td>COSU Remarks</td>".
                "<td>SMU Notes</td>".
                "<td>SUBMITTED/PENDING</td>".
                "<td> EDIT </td>".
                "</tr></thead>";

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['APP_NUMBER']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_ASSIGNED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['BORROWER_NAME']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['APP_FINISH_DATE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEVELOPER_PROJECT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COLLATERAL_ADDRESS_DETAILS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_DOCUMENT']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DEFERRED_TYPE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['ORIGINAL_DEADLINE']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['DATE_COMPLETED']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SPOC_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['FILED_LOCATION']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['JUW_MA_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['COSU_REMARKS']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SMU_NOTES']."</td>".
                 "<td>".$row['SUBMITTED_PENDING']."</td>".
                 "<td><a href='spoc_remarks.php?id=".$row['ID']."' class='lytebox'><image src='./images/pen.png' height=30 width=30></a></td>".

                 "</tr>";
    }
    }
        ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this someware just call removeDiv()

http://pastebin.com/f5EUwszt

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the div (with id=tab1) with onclick event of a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" id="cmdsearch" name="cmdsearch" value="Search" />
```

A submit button is supposed to use to submit a form. So when you click it, it submits the form data to '**beta_table.php'** and the page is refreshed. If you want to hide the div (with id=tab1), you could use a button like

```
 <input type="button" id="cmdsearch_btn" name="cmdsearch_btn" value="Search" />
```

You have to decide according to your need. When a page gets submitted using a submit button there's no point hiding a div because the page gets refreshed. I hope that helps.

Comment: now I understand. It's my first time using a button, is it the same as the  submit?

Comment: No. By default, a submit button is used to submit a form. But, you can also submit a form using a normal button using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: can you help me out about the button?

Comment: You have to first clearly define what you want. Then I can help.

Comment: when you click the submit button, the page on the div with an id of "tab_search" fetch the query and display the result then hide the div with the id of tab1

Comment: If you want to fetch some data from the server you can use ajax to fetch the data and use jQuery to hide/show div you want. In that case, a button is enough.

Comment: ajax it is then...only one problem, I don't know how to use ajax :(

Comment: So, I guess you have to learn it. You can start with jQuery Ajax. Good luck.